# Installing PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qmake

I'm trying to install PyQt on my mac so that I can install python ghost. I've already installed Qt, and SIP. I've downloaded PyQt, but when I run

```
python configure-ng.py
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Use the --qmake argument to explicitly specify a working Qt qmake.
```

Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: You should explicitly specify a working Qt make.

Comment: how do i do that? Do I download a qmake or do I create my own? I'm not very familiar with Qt.

Comment: @user3417176. qmake is part of Qt. You need to specify the path to it, with something like `--qmake path/to/qt/bin/qmake`.

Comment: @user3417176: is this now resolved?

Comment: No, I looked through all the files, but I couldn't find anything named qmake

Comment: it should be where ever you installed Qt. I think it defaults to your home directory if you didn't specify elsewhere. `python configure.py --qmake ~/Qt/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake`

Comment: If it's not in the home directory then it will probably be in /usr/local somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are on a Mac, I would use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). This worked for me the other day, but took a long time to finish:

```
brew install pyqt
```

Comment: Unfourtunately this won't play nice with virtual environments.

Comment: I recently found the [`vext.pyqt4`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vext.pyqt4) and [`vext.pyqt5`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vext.pyqt5) packages which allow the virtual environments to access a globally installed pyqt library. Works perfectly for me with the binary installer offered by [Riverbank](https://riverbankcomputing.com).

Answer (score 5):

`configure-ng.py` needs both `qmake` and `sip` to configure the build process.

The error message means that `configure-ng.py` could not locate the `qmake` executable. You need to specify its location, with something like this:

`$ python configure-ng.py --qmake=/path/to/qmake`

The location of qmake depends on 1) how you installed it and 2) the OS you are using.

For Mac OS, the less painful way (in my case) is to install `sip` and `qmake` using Homebrew

`$ brew install sip`

`$ brew install qt`

> `brew` will install them in the directory: `/usr/local/Cellar/`

Then, run `configure-ng.py` with specifying both locations:

```
$ python configure-ng.py --qmake=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/VERSION/bin/qmake --sip=/usr/local/Cellar/sip/VERSION/bin/sip
```

If all good, continue PyQt installation:

```
$ make
```

`make` takes a while (around 20 mins in my case).

And finally, install:

```
$ make install
```

> `make` may needs admin permission `$ sudo make`

Answer (score 3):

**Without command line using PyCharm IDE. Also I didn't need to install Qt.:**

- Download Python 3.6.1 (double click to install).
- Download PyCharm IDE (double click to install).

  - Go to PyCharm>Preferences>Project Interpreter.
  - Point the project interpreter path to python.3.6.1
  - '+' button, search for pyqt5. Choose PyQt5 version 5.8.2 than click install package.

[image]

Automatically it is going to install PyQt 5.8.2 and SIP. After installed just, come back to Project Interpreter and make sure that SIP was installed too. If it is not installed: '+' button and install sip.

[image]

Try this code to see if it works for you too. :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Example(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    self.setFixedSize(200, 100)
    self.setWindowTitle('Example')
    label = QLabel('Hello')
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(label)
    layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]