# PyQt install error

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, installation

```
zyl55@zyl001 MINGW64 /e/Python/PyQt5_gpl-5.9.2
$ python configure.py
Error: Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation. Try  again using
the --verbose flag to see more detail about the problem.
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Determining the details of your Qt installation...

zyl55@zyl001 MINGW64 /e/Python/PyQt5_gpl-5.9.2
$ python configure.py --verbose
Error: Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation. Try again using
the --verbose flag to see more detail about the problem.
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Determining the details of your Qt installation...
E:\Qt\Qt5.9.3\5.9.3\mingw53_32\bin\qmake.exe -o cfgtest_QtCore.mk  cfgtest_QtCore.pro
mingw32-make -f cfgtest_QtCore.mk release
'mingw32-make' ▒▒▒▒▒ڲ▒▒▒▒ⲿ▒▒▒Ҳ▒▒▒ǿ▒▒▒▒еĳ▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ļ▒▒▒
```

Comment: thanks to the PyCharm, I don't have to install PyQt now.

Comment: I get it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678954/installing-pyqt

Comment: FYI, it's use `pip` which is a tool provided with Python to manage packages